# python re invalid group reference \10

Tags: python, regex

What would be the syntax if I want to insert "0" after the first group reference ?

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("(..)(..)", "\\1x\\2", "toto")
'toxto'
>>> re.sub("(..)(..)", "\\10\\2", "toto")
sre_constants.error: invalid group reference
```

Error, because `\10` is interpreted as 10th reference group (that's why in ed(), group references are in [1-9] interval).

In the example above, how to obtain "to0to" ?

Answer (score 13):

You can use `\g` based group substitution:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("(..)(..)", r"\g<1>0\g<2>", "toto")
'to0to'
```

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

> `\g<number>` uses the corresponding group number; `\g<2>` is therefore
>   equivalent to `\2`, but isn’t ambiguous in a replacement such as `\g<2>0`.
>   `\20` would be interpreted as a reference to group `20`, not a reference
>   to group `2` followed by the literal character `'0'`.